# iOS - Storyboard - modify UIView that is out of frame with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

It's a fairly stupid question but here we go:
I am using Autolayout right now to create a UIScrollview with 3 different UIViews I am scrolling through. I all created it using Storyboard and it works perfectly -- the first View is in the middle of the frame, and the 2 other ones are horizontally out of the frame. When I scroll in the Simulator it works perfectly.
All my frames have proportional widths to the main Superview, which means that they take the whole screen's space.

My issue is that I can't access the two other views to add elements to them through the Storyboard because they are not in the frame -- even if I change the ViewController's size, all the Views just get bigger because their size is proportional to the main view's size.

[image]

I would like to add elements to the right side of my second UIView (the third one is even more to the right), but you can't drag n drop objects if it's not on the ViewController's frame.

How could I solve this issue without having to mess up all my constraints?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: "even if I change the ViewController's size, all the Views just get bigger because their size is proportional to the main view's size" but you can turn off that behavior.

Comment: By deleting the constraints you mean?

Comment: Create one xib for that view and make changes whatever you want there. Just use that view in your storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with this is go to your storyboard -> select your firstView  -> View Constraints and edit the 'Leading Constraint to Superview' constraint negative multiples of width of the screen like -320, -640. It will then show you the second and third view respectively.

Image attached below.

Note: You need to remember to set this back to 0 once you are done editing.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly ! Absolutely fantastic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag new views into the view hierarchy shown on the left, and use the same to select any items to edit them, add constraints, etc.